Can self hosted gitpod launch devcontainer instances in another AWS acccount (or even in the same account, but in ecs or ec2)
I'm exploring gitpod running self hosted in AWS and I currently have it working with a load balancer, etc.
I'm looking to run devcontainers with it, but the gitpod instances are fairly small (t3.medium). I'm looking to run tests that have multiple, possibly large, micro services. They most likely can't run on the same instance.
Is it possible for gitpod to set values in the devcontainer.json to run on other machines in the same account (ec2 or maybe an ecs task), or even in another account (given that the role hosting the gitpod has been given the ability to do that)
